# Spring/Jackson is not loading an entity from its id in a JSON RequestBody

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I have been trying to solve this problem for a few good hours and still can't do nothing.

Let me give you a little context:

- I have an Employee and Contract domain.
- Each of them is on their own Repository, and its own table.
- Contract has a unidirectional OneToOne relationship with Employee, being itself the owning class.

Contract.class

```java
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Employee employee;
```

Employee.class

```java
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "employee")
    private Contract contract;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    ... name, lastName, email, etc.
```

I also have 2 endpoints

```java
    @PostMapping("/employee")
    @ResponseBody
    public Employee newEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        return EMPLOYEE_SERVICE.saveEmployee(employee);
    }
```

```java
    @PostMapping(value = "/contract")
    @ResponseBody
    public Contract newContract(@RequestBody Contract contract) {
        return CONTRACT_SERVICE.createContract(contract);
    }
```

So this is the result of a POST to /employee:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "rfc": "ABCD0123456A7",
    "name": "Eduardo",
    "lastName": "...",
    "birthDate": "...",
    "email": "...",
    "cellPhone": "..."
}
```

The thing is, that when I post an employee, everything works fine, until I post a Contract which contains an Id reference to the employee:

```json
{
    "employeeId": 1,
    "dateFrom": "2023-01-01",
    "dateTo": "2023-10-10",
    "salaryPerDay": 200
}
```

And it is unable to get the Employee object from its id:

```json
{
    "employee": null,
    "dateFrom": "2023-01-01",
    "dateTo": "2023-10-10",
    "salaryPerDay": 200
}
```

And I'm almost 100% sure it's a Jackson's issue, not Hibernate, but I have very little knowledge and haven't found anything helpful on this specific example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How should jackson know that `employeeId` (with no corresonding field) needs to be resolved to an `Employee`? You would need a specific deserializer for this to work. Jackson doesn't know anything about JPA. What you could do is change your `employeeId` to `"employee": { "id":1 }` which would then construct an empty `Employee` which in theory should match a record in the database.

Comment: Ended up creating my own custom Jackson deserializer with [the help of this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45464777/convert-requestbody-attribute-containing-entity-id-to-corresponding-entity-in-s)